# Can I compare a user's input without assigning it to a variable?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to write a latitude/longitude program and if the user's input doesn't meet certain parameters, it isn't stored included as part of the latitude/longitude. I know I could probably make an `Array` or `ArrayList` for this assignment, but for the sake of simplicity, I simply decided to make a longitude and latitude variable. My question is, can I compare a user's input without assigning it to another variable.
Here's a snippet of my code is:

```
Scanner run = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean start = true;
double latitude;
double longtitude;
while(start) {
   System.out.println("Please enter the latitude:");
   if(!(run.nextDouble() < -90 || run.nextDouble() > 180)) { /*checking to 
                                see if the user input meets the restrictions 
                                and can therefore be assigned a variable*/
      latitude = run.nextDouble();
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Incorrect Latitude or Longtitude");
   }
```

Comment: Why not create an extra variable to hold the input? If the input is valid, then assign that variable to `latitude`.

Comment: Does that mean that if I use nextDouble() only once, then it can work?

Comment: @Letta every time you call nextDouble it reads an input. While it's a common mistake to assume you can call.it multiple times but get the same value each time, it's not how the API works.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. Each time you call `nextDouble()`, the user is going to have to provide a new input. You need to capture their input in a temporary variable to make the comparisons, then assign it to `latitude` if it passes.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are calling `run.nextDouble()` three times:

```
if(!(run.nextDouble() < -90 || run.nextDouble() > 180)) { 
     latitude = run.nextDouble();
}
```

Twice in the `if` statement and then again to assign it to `latitude`. This means that it will ask the user for new input each time you call it. If you want to use the value more than once you'll need to assign it to a variable. You have all of this in a `while` loop, so if you declared a new variable to hold the user input it would quickly fall out of scope so there isn't a lot of cost to do so:

```
while(start) {
   double temp = run.nextDouble();
   System.out.println("Please enter the latitude:");
   if(!(temp < -90 || temp > 180)) { 
      latitude = temp;
   }
   else {
      System.out.println("Incorrect Latitude or Longtitude");
   }
} //temp is now out of scope
```